# Use of future subjunctive

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

What is the difference between these three sentences?

1. Si considerases que alguno **es** útil, podríamos comprarlo.
2. Si considerases que alguno **fuere** útil, podríamos comprarlo.
3. Si considerases que alguno **fuese** útil, podríamos comprarlo.

Traditionally, the future subjunctive is replaced by the present or past subjunctive; for example, "consideraras" (present subjunctive) is used instead of "considerares" (rarely used) in these three sentences.

Now, my question is about the second verb in these sentences. Should it be also a subjunctive? Why?

Comment: There's no need for the future subjunctive here (and future subjunctive is replaced by present — either indicative or subjunctive, depending — in modern Spanish).  The future subjunctive normally is coordinated with other clauses that appear in the indicative future whether periphrastic or synthetic.  "Si **considerares** que [es/sea] útil, **podremos** comprarlo" (notice present tense in the que clause).  The choice of subjunctive or indicative in the que clause would be dictated by the same rules dictating the sentence "Si *consideras* que [es/sea], pod(r)emos comprarlo".

Comment: Another minor point: in spanish saying "consideraras" or "considerases" has no difference. Spanish speakers use a lot these words, and everything involved with "hiciera" o "hiciese," so listening something like "considerases" is way to used by spanish speakers.

Answer (score 1):

In daily speech, the three forms are equal; but, strictly speaking, they are different semantically.

1. The sentence conveys that you, *in this moment*, suppose the thing is useful.
2. The sentence conveys that you suppose that the thing *will become* useful.
3. The sentence conveys that you suppose that the thing *has been* useful.

Example: If you have a car with a broken tire, "tú consideraras que el neumático **es** útil."
On the other hand, if you don't have a car, but are thinking of buying one, "tú consideraras que el neumático **fuere** útil." Finally, if you had a car with a broken tire, "tú consideraras que el neumático **fuese** útil (in that past day)."

Regarding "consideraras" in the first option, however, "consideras" (tense present indicative) would be more commonly used.
You can visit the following website for more details:

http://www.conjugacion.es/del/verbo/considerar.php

Comment: Actually, future subjunctive can't be used in noun clauses, so *fuere* is imposible as the second verb.

Comment: Also, "tú consideraras" is used by a "si" before.

Answer (score 1):

1.Si considerases que alguno es útil, podríamos comprarlo.

> 1. La usarías en presente. Por ejemplo, si quieres comprar un libro que necesitas para hoy, y estas en la librería dirías:

```
Si crees que es útil podríamos comprarlo.
```

2.Si considerases que alguno fuere útil, podríamos comprarlo.

> 2. Esta realmente yo no la daría por correcta, además de que es una forma verbal que nunca o mejor dicho casi nunca se usa. Excepto abogados, jueces ...

**Fuere** es futuro simple del subjuntivo y suele usarse para realizar afirmaciones hipotéticas, inciertas o los deseos. El uso del subjuntivo no se usa y menos el futuro del subjuntivo, que se usa actualmente solo en el ámbito legal (para abogados, jueces ...).

```
Sea lo que fuere (aunque normalmente se diría, «Sea lo que sea»).
```

Otro ejemplo, esta vez con el verbo **insultar**

```
Quien insultare ... (se diría, «Quien insulte»)
```

3.Si considerases que alguno fuese útil, podríamos comprarlo.

> 3. Esta es Pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo, y como la anterior no se usa mucho.
>      Además no es una forma única: en realidad se podría decir **fuera** o **fuese**, aunque no en todos los casos.

Se usa en oraciones condicionales.

Por ejemplo con el verbo **amar** cuya forma en pretérito imperfecto sería **amara/amase**:

> Si yo la amara, o amase intentaría conseguirla.

Otra:

> Yo amara, o amaría el dinero, si eso me diera la felicidad.

Esta ultima forma se usa principalmente en frases asertivas o condicionales. el problema es que en español hay varias tipos de condicionales, te aconsejo que no uses estas formas si tu nivel de español no es alto.

Si necesitas una explicación de los distintos tipos de condicionales haz una pregunta en relación a eso.

Saludos.